# vagrant up failed my centos 4.1 i386 box

Tags: centos, package, vagrant

vagrant up failed

here is my "Vagrantfile"

```
#-*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION="2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
    config.vm.box = "centos41build"

    config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
            vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--cpus", "1", "--memory", "1024"]
            vb.gui = false
    end

    config.vm.define :centostest41 do |centostest41|
            centostest41.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.10.10"
            centostest41.vm.hostname = "centosfivefour"
            ## ssh
            centostest41.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 22, host: 2105
    end
end
```

that is fail messages

```
$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'centostest41' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> centostest41: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> centostest41: Fixed port collision for 22 => 2222. Now on port 2203.
==> centostest41: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> centostest41: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    centostest41: Adapter 1: nat
    centostest41: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> centostest41: Forwarding ports...
    centostest41: 22 => 2105 (adapter 1)
    centostest41: 22 => 2203 (adapter 1)
==> centostest41: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> centostest41: Booting VM...
==> centostest41: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few         minutes...
The guest machine entered an invalid state while waiting for it
to boot. Valid states are 'starting, running'. The machine is in the
'poweroff' state. Please verify everything is configured
properly and try again.

If the provider you're using has a GUI that comes with it,
it is often helpful to open that and watch the machine, since the
GUI often has more helpful error messages than Vagrant can retrieve.
For example, if you're using VirtualBox, run `vagrant up` while the
VirtualBox GUI is open.

The primary issue for this error is that the provider you're using
is not properly configured. This is very rarely a Vagrant issue.
```

this box made in myself by centos4.1i386 virtualbox

how to solve this problem?

i was search this issue. but i can't solve.... gui config -> false solution is failed

this error get when i give to vagrant debug option

INFO interface: error: The guest machine entered an invalid state while waiting for it
to boot. Valid states are 'starting, running'. The machine is in the
'poweroff' state. Please verify everything is configured
properly and try again.

If the provider you're using has a GUI that comes with it,
it is often helpful to open that and watch the machine, since the
GUI often has more helpful error messages than Vagrant can retrieve.
For example, if you're using VirtualBox, run `vagrant up` while the
VirtualBox GUI is open.

The primary issue for this error is that the provider you're using
is not properly configured. This is very rarely a Vagrant issue.
The guest machine entered an invalid state while waiting for it
to boot. Valid states are 'starting, running'. The machine is in the
'poweroff' state. Please verify everything is configured
properly and try again.

If the provider you're using has a GUI that comes with it,
it is often helpful to open that and watch the machine, since the
GUI often has more helpful error messages than Vagrant can retrieve.
For example, if you're using VirtualBox, run `vagrant up` while the
VirtualBox GUI is open.

The primary issue for this error is that the provider you're using
is not properly configured. This is very rarely a Vagrant issue.
 INFO interface: Machine: error-exit ["Vagrant::Errors::VMBootBadState", "The guest machine entered an invalid state while waiting for it\nto boot. Valid states are 'starting, running'. The machine is in the\n'poweroff' state. Please verify everything is configured\nproperly and try again.\n\nIf the provider you're using has a GUI that comes with it,\nit is often helpful to open that and watch the machine, since the\nGUI often has more helpful error messages than Vagrant can retrieve.\nFor example, if you're using VirtualBox, run `vagrant up` while the\nVirtualBox GUI is open.\n\nThe primary issue for this error is that the provider you're using\nis not properly configured. This is very rarely a Vagrant issue."]

Comment: Did you enable virtualisation in your boot menu?

Comment: different vagrant box is well done in same server...but, only this box is not running.

Comment: try turning `vb.gui = true` and run `vagrant up --debug` see what you get. also check you can start the VM directly form VirtualBox

Comment: directly from VirtualBox is well done in my computer but i hope to run in server without gui.